# Where will the file be created?

Tags: python, file, temporary-files

```
import tempfile

storage_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')
    with open(STORAGE_PATH, 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

In which directory will the file be created? And is it possible to see it there or is it invisible?

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.tempdir), this should answer your question.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir

Comment: What file? Your code doesn't create any files.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? The [`tempfile.gettempdir()` function docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) spell this out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir)...

The list is:

- the directory named by the `TMPDIR` environment variable
- the directory named by the `TEMP` environment variable
- the directory named by the `TMP` environment variable
- a platform-specific location:

  - on Windows, the directories `C:\TEMP`, `C:\TMP`, `\TEMP`, and `\TMP`, in that order.
  - on all other platforms, the directories `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, and `/usr/tmp`, in that order.
  - as a last resort, the current working directory.

A sample from mac os :

```
/var/folders/4x/2rjwjpyn1pn9_0t1r5_m8blr0000gn/T/storage.data
```

When you go to the directory via finder the file should be there. As for Windows it might be hidden which I believe you can unlock.

Answer (score 1):

You only created a *string*, nothing more.

The [`tempfile.gettempdir()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) returns a string:

> Return the name of the directory used for temporary files

It's just a name. Print it if you need to know the location on your system but don't want to step through the rules outlined in the documentation; there are 3 environment variables and another 3 standard locations to test to see where the current user has permission to create files.

Next, `os.path.join()` takes strings and outputs a string. Nothing is created on disk to build these strings. It'll depend on whether or not you actually do something with that string (like calling [`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) or `open()`) on what will be created.

If you use a plain `open()` call on that string then a regular file is created in the `tempfile.gettempdir()` location that is visible to other processes.

If you need to create a temporary file *securely*, so in a manner that an attacker can't access the file or influence where it is created, use the [`tempfile.TemporaryFile()` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) or the [`tempfile.mkstemp()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp); on UNIX systems that'll result in a file that is not listed in the directory any more (the file exists but can't be opened by other processes). It will be created in the `tempfile.gettempdir()` location however, so it'll use up disk space on the relevant disk partition that that directory lives on.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no file being created. Check out the [tempfile documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) to find more information about functions of the module such as the `.gettempdir()`:

> Python searches a standard list of directories to find one which the
>   calling user can create files in. The list is:
>
> 1. The directory named by the TMPDIR environment variable.
> 2. The directory named by the TEMP environment variable.
> 3. The directory named by the TMP environment variable.
> 4. A platform-specific location:
>         On Windows, the directories C:\TEMP, C:\TMP, \TEMP, and \TMP, in that order.
>         On all other platforms, the directories /tmp, /var/tmp, and /usr/tmp, in that order.
> 5. As a last resort, the current working directory.